# edit file using python multiple modifications

Tags: python

I have a file in the following format (over 200 lines)

```
{'HostIo: 1328, 'ReadIo': 829, 'WriteIo':220, 'timestamp': 1529133380000}

{'HostIo: 4328, 'ReadIo': 3729, 'WriteIo':420, 'timestamp': 1529133390000}
```

and i would like to edit the file. Better to edit inplace or a new file for a new programmer ?

These are modifications i would like to do

- replace `:` with `=`
- delete all single quotes and `{}` and the word `'timestamp'`
- add word `'server_name'` at the beginning of every line.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What OS are you using?  Where does the source file come from? What is the purpose of the file's persistence ?

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input('yourfile', inplace=True):
    line = line.replace(':', '=')
    for delete in ("'", '{', '}', 'timestamp'):
        line = line.replace(delete, '')
    print('server_name', line)
```